# Sharing Wi-Fi between Apple products

Tags: iphone, network, wifi, macos

Since I installed Mavericks, I cannot access internet (Eduroam) on my university, and they said are working on an solution (2 weeks ago) and I can't wait anymore, but my iPhone and iPad still can access the Wi-Fi network. What options do I have?

Is there any possibility to share my iPhone or iPad Wi-Fi with my MacBook using iOS 7 without jailbreaking it? I can't turn on my hotspot option, without turning on the cellular data sharing.

Should I downgrade Mavericks and solve the problem with the Internet? Or should I downgrade one of my devices, jailbreak it and install an app to share the Wi-Fi connection?

Comment: What do you see when you open Network preferences and try connecting Ethernet?  Have you tried removing the Ethernet port from Network prefs or from the `networksetup` command, rebooting and then re-adding it?  Jailbreaking seems like total overkill.

Comment: It says connected, but works really bad or sometimes doesn’t work, so i am stuck. I think there’s a problem beyond the wifi. About the Ethernet port, i didn’t make anything, the only thing i did, was re-install the wifi configs a lot of times, but without success, the actual wifi network profile is not accepted on mavericks, and my university wont update it for now, maybe there's any possibilty to adapt other's university profile to mine. Making the changes on the Ethernet port as you said will make any differences on wifi?

Comment: Does your university require to you login through a captive portal? This is one thing that changed in mavericks. Also, have you tried deleting the network profile in network prefs as well as in your keychain?

Comment: Yes, login is required. And i deleted from keychain and installed from zero a lot of times, inclusive i changed the prefs to trust all network profiles, well everything that was in the apple forums about the problem, i tried.